# SQL: Extract specific part of string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substring, regexp-like

I'm trying to figure out how to extract a specific part of a string (made out of multiple terms) with a select statement in **Oracle SQL**.

The values in the column look somewhat like `'2E WK 12-345-678 TM 13-06-2017'`, which has a slight variation in format in each row.

Now I want to create a new column that displays only the `'123-456-789'` part from each row. The question now is: How can you identify this exact format of *3 numbers, hyphen, 3 numbers, hyphen, 3 numbers* from each row?

SUBSTR(...) didn't do it for me since the part in question is not always in the same position. Then I tried to apply REGEXP_LIKE(...) 
but this doesn't return the right values either.

How should I write the SQL statement to do this? Help is very much appreciated.

Example of strings:

```
2E XX **18-580-0111**
**18-990-0020**: 11.2.11-11.14.19
**65-660-0838** 2015 xxxx core sysxx
**78-140-401** t/m 0019

** = specific part of the string that's needed
```

Kind regards!

Comment: Take a look at REGEXP_SUBSTR()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question can directly be translated into a regular expression, for `regexp_substr()`:

```
select col, regexp_substr(col, '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}')
```